# InputStream vs Reader

Tags: java, inputstream, streamreader, java-io

I am going over input output section and there are so much classes and interfaces that I am confused a little bit.
As documentation says `InputStream` is a byte based stream whereas `Reader` is character-based stream. But as I understood correctly the only difference between them is that `Reader` reads two bytes per time instead of one byte at a time as `InputStream` does. 
 Therefore I don't understand is there any difference:
**Using** `InputStream`

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    int bytesRead = in.read(bytes);
    while(bytesRead != -1) {
      doSomethingWithData(data);
      bytesRead = inputstream.read(data);
    }
```

**Using** `Reader`

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
int data = reader.read();
while (data != -1) {
   doSomethingWithData(data);
   data = reader.read();
}
```

I am really confusing about these aspects. Explain please in details. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the charset, a character may be 1 or 2 (or even more) byte(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Reader` to read text data. And it's supports some character encoding like - ISO, UTF-8. If you want to read a text file with some encoding then you can use `Reader`s like - `BufferedReader`,  `StringReader` etc.

And you can use `Stream (InputStream, OutputStream)` to manipulate binary data. For example you want to read a image file then you can use `FileInputStream` and when you want to save it to disk then you can use `FileOutputStream`.